# How to make SDK connection to an S3 bucket persistent?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using the `boto3` library to put objects in Amazon S3. I want to make a python service on my server, which is connected to the bucket in AWS, and whenever I send it a file path, it puts that in the bucket:

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    endpoint_url='...',
    aws_access_key_id='...',
    aws_secret_access_key='...'
)
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('name')
```

for uploading, I send my requests to this method:

```
def upload(path):
    bucket.put_object(...)
```

The connection to the bucket should be persistent so that whenever I call `upload` method, it quickly puts the object in the bucket and does not need to connect to the bucket every time.

How can I enable long-lived connections on my `s3_resource`?

Comment: I don't think that such "persistence" concepts apply to Amazon S3. The `put_object()` command makes an API call to the Amazon S3 service. AWS then responds and disconnects. There is no 'connection' to keep open and there is certainly no "connection to a bucket". What problem are you experiencing that you wish to solve by all this?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein so if I get the bucket by `bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('name')`, I can call `bucket.put_object()` on this bucket instance after 10 hrs of inactivity? or it will be disconnected and I will have to get a new bucket instance?

Comment: You can do that, the underlying network connection will most likely be re-established, so the latency would be a bit higher after such a long time, but you don't have to change anything about your app for that. It's handled by the SDK.

Comment: @Maurice great! this answers what I was looking for! thanks.

Comment: Cool, I've edited my answer a bit to elaborate on that @Soheil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

The SDK tries to be an abstraction from the underlying API calls.
Whenever you want to put an object into an S3 bucket, that results in an API call. API calls are sent over the network to AWS and that requires establishing a connection to an AWS server. This connection can be kept open for a longer time, so it doesn't need to be re-established every time you want to make an API call. This helps reduce the network overhead, since establishing connections is relatively costly.

From your perspective these should be implementation details, you shouldn't have to worry about, since the SDK (boto3) takes care of that for you. There are some options to tweak how it handles things, but these are considered advanced options and you should know what you're doing ;-)

The lifecycle of the resources in boto3 is more or less independent from the underlying network connection. The way you will see this impact you, is through higher latencies, when there is **no** pre-existing connection that can be repurposed.

---

What you're looking for are the keep-alive options in boto3.

There is two levels on which these can be enabled:

**TCP**

- You can set the `tcp_keepalive` option in the SDK config, which is set to `false` by default.
- More detail on that can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/setting-global-tcp_keepalive.html).

**HTTP**

- For HTTP-Keep alive, there is nothing you need to do explicitly - the underlying library handles that implicitly. There is a common optimization suggestion when using [aws-sdk-js](/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-js) to mess with this, but the SDKs behave differently, that's not necessary in Python. There is a long discussion about this in a [Github issue](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1677).
- If you want to set configure the setting explicitly, you can use the event system to do that as [this reply](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1677#issuecomment-471002891) suggests:

```py
def set_connection_header(request, operation_name, **kwargs):
    request.headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'

ddb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
ddb.meta.events.register('request-created.dynamodb', set_connection_header)
```